# WebBrowser control says "Navigation to the webpage was canceled"

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using Windows 10 and I already changed the registry keys so the WebBrowser control uses the latest version of IE.

I only seem to be getting this error for a specific site. Other sites seem to be loading fine. I'm also not getting this problem on IE. It's only on the WebBrowser control. This happens no matter how many times I reload the page.

This seems to be happening 90% of the times. There are some cases where the page actually loads. I'm not sure what I'm doing differently though, since my code is the same.

Comment: Can you monitor HTTP connections made by your application? Fiddler might help to see what exactly is sent and received over the wire.

Comment: @Alexei so I guess I'm able to do it (even though I don't understand what I'm seeing completely). Is there any log you need in order to help?

Comment: Fiddler or similar app should display request and received data (headers, content) from which you can understand where the problem can be. Also, you can take a look into the Event Viewer to see if an event is generated there. Just a wild guess: it might be related to some security setting (browser related) that does not allow to make connection to that particular URL.